# Twitter Bootstrap: modal dialogue tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**What I want:** disable opening `a`-references in new browser tab/window.

**Possible solution:** Replace `href` attribute of `a`-reference with `data-href`.

**Problem:** Due twitter bootstrap implementation, to switch across modal dialog tabs you must use `href` attribute; `data-href` doesn't work.

**Question:** How should I change bootstrap.css to make it work for `data-href` attribute?

**Demo:** You can play with [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/168/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple: add `oncontextmenu="return false;"` to the `ul` element.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home Tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can do this by just by css...

But maybe this alternative way could help you ?

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/169/

*In JS : Create data-href attribute, remove the original href, and perform the active class change manually...*

**JS** :

```
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm').modal("show");  
});

$('[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function(){
    var dest = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('data-href',dest).removeAttr('href');
    $(this).on('click', function(){
       $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
       $(dest).addClass('active'); 
    });
});
```